# Javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript

i try to use confirm box but it does not work after 'OK' pressing
this is my confirm box

```
<script language="JavaScript">
{literal}
function confirmBox()
{
 var where_to= confirm("Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?");
 if (where_to== true)
     return true;
 else{
     alert("Silme işleminden vazgeçtiniz yönlendiriliyorsunuz");
     return false;
 }
}
{/literal}
</script>



 <form name="removeFortune" method="post" action="#">
    <table border="0" name="tableArticle">
     {foreach from=$articles value=article}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkArticle[]" value="{$article.id}" /></td>
            <td>{$article.title}</td>
        </tr>
        {/foreach}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" onclick="confirmBox()" name="removeArticle" value="Sil" />
    <br /><br />

    {$deleteMessage}

</form>
```

Comment: When user clicks on " OK ", it will come in if condition. you have written return true .. it will comes out of JS function... what else you expect?

Comment: homework :D     i dont think so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want it to submit after pressing OK, you need to change 1 simple thing. Add a return

```
onclick="return confirmBox()"
```

Although I would say:

```
onsubmit="return confirmBox()"
```